# Handling alert after action chain in IE, webdriver

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, alert

I have a customized drop-down menu and I need to click one of it's options. After it is clicked - alert appear. So I build a chain

```
InvokeChain(() => Actions.MoveToElement(button).MoveToElement(targetOption).Click(targetOption));

protected static void InvokeChain(Func<Actions> chain)
        {
            chain.Invoke().Build().Perform();
        }
```

In chrome it works fine, but when it comes to IE - driver cannot handle quit the chain. I think, it happens because of alert. Error message at chain line:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://..... click timed out after 60 seconds.

The question is how could I release driver from chain to handle alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set EnableNativeEvents = true

```
InternetExplorerOptions internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions
{
   EnableNativeEvents = true
};
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerOptions);
```